# ctermbg and ctermfg are backwards or incorrect for certain highlighting groups

Tags: terminal, colorscheme, statusline, color

I am currently attempting to create a custom colorscheme for vim by using `ctermfg` and `ctermbg` values, and checking what the colorscheme looks like with the highlight test file provided by Vim.

What I do not understand is why `ctermfg` and `ctermbg` appear backwards, and also incorrect, for certain highlighting groups. `StatusLine`, for instance, is set to have a black foreground and a white background, but instead has a white foreground and a gray background. Is there something special about specific highlighting groups that I should keep in mind when I set their colors?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! In the future, [please don't post images of text](https://benknoble.github.io/blog/2019/11/24/pics-text/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're probably overlooking the additional attributes set in the `cterm=` field for those highlights.

For instance, after I set `ctermfg=black ctermbg=white` for `StatusLine`, I get this when I query it:

```
:hi StatusLine
StatusLine     xxx term=bold,reverse cterm=bold,reverse
                   ctermfg=0 ctermbg=15 gui=bold,reverse
```

You'll see the `cterm=bold,reverse` there, which is part of the defaults for `StatusLine`. In particular, `reverse` will swap fg & bg colors, which is the effect you're seeing.

Since those attributes are set in a separate field (`cterm=`), which you're not overriding, the defaults are being preserved.

To undo the effects of this field, you could set it explicitly, with:

```
hi StatusLine cterm=bold
```

Or, to also drop the `bold` attribute:

```
hi StatusLine cterm=reverse
```

Or you could just decide to embrace the default of using reverse colors on the `StatusLine` and perhaps some other highlight groups and just set your fg & bg colors in reverse, to then have the reversing applied by `cterm=` get the colors as you actually want them.

Also consider the `term=` (for B&W terminals) and `gui=` (for gvim) attributes, if you're considering setting custom highlighting that you'd like to work on those environments as well.